# Showing empty space at bottom when i use TabBarController at top

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

[image]

I am getting empty space at the bottom, when i have UITabBarController at top of the screen.In iOS7 it is working using this code

```
       self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeBottom;
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
```

//Where as in ios 6 getting empty space.Below is the code i have used to show tabbar

```
    appDelegate.tabBarController.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 50);
appDelegate.tabBarController.delegate=self;

UIView *view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -20, 320, 600)];

viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

TagViewController *view1 = [[TagViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav1=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:view1];
[viewControllers addObject:nav1];

ContactsViewController *view2 = [[ContactsViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav2=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:view2];
[viewControllers addObject:nav2];

MessagesViewController *view3 = [[MessagesViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav3=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:view3];
[viewControllers addObject:nav3];

RewardsViewController *view4 = [[RewardsViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav4=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:view4];
[viewControllers addObject:nav4];

SettingsViewController *view5 = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav5=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:view5];
[viewControllers addObject:nav5];

[appDelegate.tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

appDelegate.tabBarController.tabBarController.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[view addSubview:appDelegate.tabBarController.view];

[self.view addSubview:view];
```

Comment: Are you making this in interface builder? There's a chance you dragged it in the wrong spot, maybe into the table view.

Comment: i created tabbar using coding.And the table view is placed ten pixels below the tabbar.

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: @user1264105 Try making it in interface builder. Make all your code items IBOutlets and just link them up. See if the problem persists.

Comment: @morokko: i shared the code.can you please check.In ios7 working fine.it is not working in iOS6.

Comment: can any suggest the solutions

Comment: is there any solution for ios 6?

Answer (score -1):

Try this code in your viewWillAppear:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
```

or

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: If i do this then tabbar will hide.But i want to remove the empty space at the bottom